# Row to Column conversion in Talend

Tags: talend

I am learning Talend Open studio. I want to implement the scenario where a row converts into 3 rows. My Source is like

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
a        b       c
```

I want to get the output like below

```
Col
a
b
c
```

I have used tcolumntopivotdelimited but failed.

[image]

Comment: Would you add your code to the question please (and get into that habit for all questions that you ask)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution :

[image]

In your tmap you need to concat with a ";" for example and normalize the resulted column with the good delimiter

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!