# Convert rows to columns using Talend Open Studio for DI

Tags: talend

```
2PAN;4189670095711234

4Transation Amount;11.00

7Transmission Date and Time;04/12/yy 06:30:05

32Acquring Institution ID;826-United Kingdom

37Retrieval Ref Num;12346789

49Transaction currency code;784 - UAE Dirham
```

The above one is the data that i have. I need it converted to as given below

```
2PAN;4Transation Amount;7Transmission Date and Time;32Acquring Institution 
4189670095711234;11.00;04/12/yy 06:30:05;826-United Kingdom
```

I want the first column of the delimited file to be the row values and second column to be the respective row values of the above.
How to do it using Talend Open Studio for DI. I had tried tPivotTocolumns and tSplitRow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row to Column conversion in Talend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463671/row-to-column-conversion-in-talend)

Answer (score 0):

Try using **tSplitRow** component to "Pivot" rows and columns, according to your need based on your schema.

Refer http://desireddata.blogspot.com/2015/04/how-to-use-tsplitrow-component-in-talend.html

Thanks,

Sekar.